# push changes to github using batch file with username and password

Tags: batch-file, github-for-windows

I have the following running in a batch file

```
cd c:/dirtogithubrepo
git config --global user.name "my name"
git config --global user.email "myemail@mydomain.com"
git init
git status
git add data.js
git commit -m "Add data.js"
git remote -v
git push
pause
```

which does push the file up to git hub. my problem is that it asks me for my username and password every time it runs. Is there a way to add these in the process? or can anyone think of a work around

thanks

Comment: You could use ssh instead of a password

Answer (score 2):

You should be using an SSH key to connect to your repository, this allows for you to not have to use a password - [please see here for instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-windows)

The basic steps are to:

```
Generate your Keys
Upload your Public Key to Github (Settings > SSH Keys)
Set up Git to use these keys
```

The link above talks you through this!

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I've managed to create the key but i'm using github for windows and I can't find anywhere in there to add the ssh file.

Comment: you will need to login to the website and add the keys on there under your account, there are also instructions on that link for Github on windows - follow them carefully!

Comment: Hi, got all that done. I'm now struggling to add the private key. Have you any clues? thanks

Comment: Login to Github.com and you add the public key under your  user profile as described here https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-your-account  - READ the article!